# JFrog Artifactory REST API access using X-JFrog-Art-Api

Tags: docker, artifactory

We are using JFrog artifactory 4.1.0. From their docs (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API), we can either use basic authentication or specify X-JFrog-Art-Api header using API key.

Tried the following call

```
curl -X GET -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<my-key>" https:/<host>/artifactory/api/build
```

I am getting a message saying authentication is required (shown below). How can i access REST API calls using token alone? Is there anything else i need to do?

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Authentication is required"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of "X-JFrog-Art-Api" for authentication is supported since version [4.4.3](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+4.4.3). It will not work with older versions.